# Stance on repost question instead of editing to invalidate answers?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, asking-questions

Regarding [Classical RPG Item Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388509/classical-rpg-item-handling), made by me, and general questions in this matter.

I did receive decent answers on the question that was asked, but it wasn't asked clear enough by me I now see. I do not want to invalidate the answers by completely restructuring the question.

Should one post a new question ignoring the other?

or

Should one refer to their old post and writing a short "because x I reposted this..."?

Comment: If they're going to invalidate the current answers, I think that's enough to not consider it a repost

Comment: related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If, based on your improved understanding of the situation, you actually have a new/different  question that you want to ask to help solve the same actual problem you had before, then you should post a new question, optionally linking to the old one.

If you have the exact same question, and are simply clarifying the question so that future readers will be more likely to understand *what you were asking from the start* (or at least what you thought you were asking) then you should just edit the existing question.

---

If someone misunderstood the question that you were asking and ended up answering some other question then that is a problem with their answer, and while it is a bit unfortunate to now have this incorrect answer there, it shouldn't inhibit fixing the question.

If the question was understood correctly and it simply wasn't a question that would help you solve some underlying problem, then it would be wrong to "remove" a valid question/answer pair, which is why you should be asking an entirely new question if you simply realized you didn't ask what you meant to ask, or if the actual question you have has changed based on information you've picked up from the first question.